# Grab data from a given DataTable (I'd like to make a list of dictionaries)

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

This is given DataTable (Actual one's structure is changable, its columns and rows)

```
        DataTable multiDic = new DataTable();
        multiDic.Columns.Add( "English", typeof( string ) );
        multiDic.Columns.Add( "Chinese", typeof( string ) );
        multiDic.Columns.Add( "Japanese", typeof( string ) );
        multiDic.Rows.Add( "one", "one_c", "one_j" );
        multiDic.Rows.Add( "two", "two_c", "two_j" );
```

I'd like to make this kind of data containers. Progmmatically.

```
        var English = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        English.Add( "one", "" );
        English.Add( "two", "" );

        var Chinese = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Chinese.Add( "one_c", "" );
        Chinese.Add( "two_c", "" );

        var Japanese = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Japanese.Add( "one_j", "" );
        Japanese.Add( "two_j", "" );
```

So, I have tried like this. With no gain.

```
        var diclList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        foreach( DataColumn Lan in multiDic.Columns )
        {
            //var Lan.ColumnName = new Dictionary<string, string>();   //  not working..
            diclList.Add( new Dictionary<string, string>() );
        }

        foreach( DataRow line in multiDic.Rows )
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach( var cell in line.ItemArray )
            {
                diclList[i].Add( cell.ToString(), "" );      //  not working..
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: A dictionary should have keys and values. Do you really want to make these dictionary values empty strings? If so, why not simply store them as hashsets?

Comment: What it looks like you are missing is a Key column in your DataTable. Then the key can be used in each dictionary to look up English, Chinese and Japanese translations respectively, and no one language is treated differently to any other. That way, it would make sense to use dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks. Rob for your comments. From time to time I have to check "the same item or not" the Hastset eat the same item silently. I do not like it though they say it is fast. The DataTable is "given". For my side, I am just processing it.

Comment: Ah, and in some situation (yesterday, in Parallel loop), the Hashset works not properly. That is real why, I guess.